# Why can't exception handling deal with asynchronous events?

Tags: java, events, asynchronous, exception

> - Exception handling is not designed to process problems associated with asynchronous events (e.g., disk I/O completions, network message arrivals, mouse clicks and keystrokes), which occur in parallel with, and independent of, the program’s flow of control.

**How is exception handling not designed to handle asynchronous events?  Why is this the case?**

I'll be thankful if you enhanced your answers by quite detailed examples.

Comment: Can you provide your source? Exceptions arising due to asynchronous events can also be handled with the appropriate design.

Comment: So, cant we use PrimeNumbersFoundException to know if a=b*c has any prime numbers at the same time?

Comment: @assylias looks like "Jave For Programmers"   http://books.google.com/books?id=Xq9P8xly6iUC&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=%22Exception+handling+is+not+designed+to+process+problems+associated+with+asynchronous%22&source=bl&ots=-AJ6ABwzFd&sig=JynRXmydQ-w9LWDLuenLKOiSUqc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2IfNUbzNBonJ0QHbioGQDQ&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAQ

Comment: Every asynchronous event (or its immediate result) will at some point be in the program's control flow. At this point, an exception can be thrown and handled.

Comment: Notice the phrasing "problems associated with". A time-out is a problem associated with async events, and can easily be handled via exceptions. I call BS on that statement.

Comment: @assylias it's Java how to program 9th edition http://goo.gl/loVs4.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is a misleading statement.

Asynchronous work is done through threads in Java (or processes but that is a different matter).

What is true is that if you start a thread and an exception is thrown in that thread, you won't be able to catch it from your main thread.

But nothing prevents you from handling exceptions in that new thread.

Example - the code below prints `Exception was raised in the thread but we can still handle it`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException("oops");
        }
    });
    t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Exception was raised in the thread but we can still handle it");
        }
    });

    t.start();
}
```

Alternatively, you can add some exception catching logic within the Runnable itself.